# How do I properly set up my flutter project to make calls to Cloud Functions?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

### The setup

I started learning Flutter a few months ago and am now trying to integrate an existing Firebase project into a new Flutter project. I created the new app in the Firebase Console, and followed Google's [setup instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios). I am importing the necessary libraries and am using the flutter default app as a playground for me. I have a button set up so that when you press it, it calls `_doFirebaseStuff()` like so:

```dart
Future<void> _doFirebaseStuff() async {
    HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable("loadNews");
    var data = await callable.call(); // This line causes the error
    print(data);
}
```

### The problem

The expected behavior, of course, is to call the Cloud Function and return the data.

What ends up actually happening is the following error being thrown: `FirebaseFunctionsException ([firebase_functions/1] The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted`. I haven't been able to find anything in the Flutter or Firebase documentation, nor anything relevant in the source code around the stack trace.

### Troubleshooting

I have suspicions that one of the following reasons can be at the root of this issue:

- Improper configuration of Firebase (I don't have a Google-Services.plist file anywhere in my project)
- AppCheck is screwing things up

  - I don't think this is the issue because:

    - I have tested the same setup with (what I think was) a correct implementation of AppCheck
    - I am not getting a `Failed Precondition: The request must come from a verified app` message
    - The function call is not showing up in the Cloud Function logs, so I don't think the request is even being made and then denied, it fails right away
- Improper IAM permissions on the Cloud Console

  - I don't think this is the issue because:

    - I am successfully using these functions in a different app
    - The function call is not even showing up in the Console logs

However there could be other things that I'm not thinking of.

### Environment

- Language: Dart
- Flutter Version: 3.0.2
- Target platform: MacOS
- pubspec.yaml data:

  - cloud_functions: ^3.2.17
  - firebase_core: ^1.18.0

---

I'm tearing my hair out trying to debug this and would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you follow [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/macos/#generating-a-firebase-project-configuration-file) and [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/macos/#installing-your-firebase-configuration-file) ?
These instructions will help you setup the `Google-Services.plist` file.

Also, if after setting up your app as per the instructions, if you still face errors, please surround your call to the function like this:

```dart
try {
  HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable("loadNews");
  final result =
      await callable.call();
  print(data);
} on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
  print(error.code);
  print(error.details);
  print(error.message);
}
```

And share what you get in the logs (The error code, details and message will be printed in the logs).

Comment: Yup, I was missing the `com.apple.security.network.client` entitlement. Thank you so much!